# How to create truly static class in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I know there are `companion object` and `@JvmStatic`, but what I do something like that:

```
class Demo {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun foo() {
            println("foo")
        }
        fun bar() {
            println("bar")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Demo.javaClass.methods.forEach { println("${it.name} static: ${Modifier.isStatic(it.modifiers)}") }
}
```

I will get:

```
foo static: false
bar static: false
wait static: false
wait static: false
wait static: false
equals static: false
toString static: false
hashCode static: false
getClass static: false
notify static: false
notifyAll static: false
```

Is there a way to create truly static java method?

Comment: Warning in IDEA says: The resulting type of this 'javaClass' call is Class<Demo.Companion> and not Class<Demo>. Please use the more clear '::class.java' syntax to avoid confusion

Comment: Take a look at bytecode. `foo()` is compiled as a non-static method of `Demo$Companion` class, and as a static method of `Demo` class.